# How to edit multiple layers using the marquee tool?

Tags: layers, transform

I have 3 layers that I edited with blending options (one with R checked off, one with G checked off, one with B checked off, as I'm trying to create a glitch effect).

However, I can't merge these layers, as it would ruin the effects. I did some research and found that it is impossible to merge layers that have blending options without ruining its effects. This is a problem as I want to make a selection in my layers using the marquee tool, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to free transform it, and move it elsewhere.

Is it possible to do this to multiple layers at once?

I'm trying to recreate Something like this:

[image]

Comment: What program are you using?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what exactly you are doing.

If you can merge the layers *including* the solid background layer they are being blended with then that will work no problem.

If you only want to merge the layers that have blending modes applied then no, that won't work. Theres no way to rasterize a live blending mode, only its result and there is no way to have multiple blending modes on a single layer.

So you have two options:

1. Merge with the background layer and transform everything at the same time.
2. Save the selection you're working with and transform each layer individually.

Answer (score 0):

Correct. Your effects go away when being merged with other players. (I presume you're using Photoshop?)

If you don't want to lose the effects but want to merge the layers into one layer, I would suggest individually rasterizing, and then selecting them and merging them together (select each layer, ctrl+e).

A little more specifics and visuals would help us to understand better what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Is the background black or a dark colour? If it is, you can place the layers inside a group, and merge the group. Then, you can set the merged layer’s blend mode to screen and it’ll be the same, if you’re talking about a white object on a black background.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to merge all the layers, Select layers and convert into smart objects. After this, you can easily change the color and layers styles.